# How can I access handlers defined in config?

Tags: python, logging

I have following logging configuration:

```
logging.config.dictConfig({
    'version': 1,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
        'summary_verbose': {
            'level': 0,
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'summary_debug.log',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {

        'myapp': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'WARNING',
        },
    }
})
```

There is one unused handler 'summary_verbose', I want to use it for loggers which I'll create later (I do not want to configure entire handler and formatter in my app code, I want to configure it mostly once near logging initialization. Is there a way to use this handler later?
I.e. how can I write something like code below?

```
log_core = logging.getLogger('myapp.some_routine')
log_core.addHandler('summary_verbose')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a **solution** (tested on python 2.7):

```
import logging

summary_verbose_handler = logging.config.logging._handlers['summary_verbose']

log_core = logging.getLogger('myapp.some_routine')
log_core.addHandler(summary_verbose_handler)
```

But, such action is not a best practice.
If you need the handler to be launched by some condition, then you better implement some [filter logic](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#filter-objects).

Here is an example of simple filter: https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.7.x/django/utils/log.py#L160

Comment: Note that using the internal `logging._handlers` could cause breakage of this code, should the logging internals change in the future. It's better to implement a filter, as suggested, if you don't want stuff sent out by the handler some of the time.